# css and jquery not loading properly on ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a web app built using Jquery Mobile. The problem is that from the menu when i click on a link through the menu the css and the jquery doesn't load properly. This happens only when the pages as grabbed through ajax request.

When the ajax request is disabled or page is refreshed the layout gets back to normal

Please check the below link
http://www.vidznet.com/ng1/test/chart.html

From the menu when you click on the profile link you will see the layout is completely messed up. Once refreshed it comes back to normal.

Can someone tell me what might be causing it? I want to make it work without disabling the ajax request to grab the pages.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typeo in your link tag in *chart.html*.

You spelled **vendor** as **endor**

Comment: can you include the relevant code that you're running for AJAX?

The styles don't exist on the initial page at load time, so I suspect that you're doing a get somewhere and only pulling out the content at and ID and not doing anything with that page's styles.

Comment: actually im using jqueru mobile http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/navigation-linking-pages/ which has a feature that will automatically load the pages with an ajax call. Im not using a separate function for that. Just only whats builtin with jquery mobile

Comment: I wonder if your scripts are also loading. Try linking to your stylesheets from within the data-page div and see what happens. Maybe JQueryUI doesn't know to look for things in the head.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Jquery UI. Looks like they are not compatible.. Once i removed the Jquery UI It worked